# Does the JavaScript DOMContentLoaded event listener have any advantage over an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've replaced jQuery's `.onReady()` function with both of the following.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        alert("Page Loaded");
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
    (() => {
        alert("Page Loaded");
    })();
</script>
```

They both work.  My question is simply, does `DOMContentLoaded` provide any advantage?  Or does it "catch" things that the anonymous function might "miss"?  Or are they both perfectly equivalent?

**EDIT:** I failed to mention in the original post (and it's been pointed out that its location is important) that this `<script>` is at the bottom of the page following the closing `</html>` tag.

Comment: If the code within your anonymous function accesses the DOM, it needs to be placed after the elements it accesses. The DOMContentLoaded eventlistener could be bound earlier in the document. If both scripts where placed at the end of the document, they would be interchangeable.

Comment: The anonymous function does not guarantee that the DOM is fully ready when invoked: it depends on where it is placed. Meanwhile listening to the `DOMContentLoaded` event guarantees that.

Comment: Honestly, you should learn to put your `<script src='external.js'></script>` tags in your `<head>`, and use external JavaScript with a `load` Event instead, so your scripts have access to each other.

Comment: I do not know who decides "this question already has answers", or if it's done by a bot.  But my question has nothing to do with the placement of the script, and all of the answers are jQuery solutions, which I specifically said I was not using.  The question is specifically, and only about the difference between an anon function that runs at the bottom of the page, and the DOMContentLoaded event, and which is more complete or exhaustive?  The question is well formed, relevant, and properly structured, and not answered by any of the proposed already-asked questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're completely different. The anonymous function (you mean an immediately-invoked function expression, or IIFE) may "work" in your particular context, but unlike the `DOMContentLoaded` event it doesn't wait for the DOM to load.

If you tried the IIFE approach in the `head` and your code tried to interact with the DOM, it would fail.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script>
    (() => {
        let p = document.querySelector('p'); //null
    })();
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let p = document.querySelector('p'); //object
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Roger that.  I updated the question with additional info about the placement of this script.  Thank you (and others) for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry for the LONG delay in accepting your answer.